# Upload image with axios in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, file-upload, axios

I want to upload image in react native and using `react-native-cameraroll` for getting image:

I try this for sending data:

```
const fileName = photo.node.image.filename || photo.node.image.uri.split("/").reverse()[0];
body.append(
  "photo",
  { uri: photo.node.image.uri, type: photo.node.type, name: fileName },
);
```

But not works. and What sent to server is `photo: [object Object]`

I also tried with `JSON.parse({ uri: photo.node.image.uri, type: photo.node.type, name: fileName })`

In postman upload works and what post give me as code is this for axios:

```
data.append('photo', fs.createReadStream('SRC/FILE_NAME.png'));
```

and this for XHR:

```
data.append("photo", fileInput.files[0], "FILE_NAME.png");
```

How can I used these codes to upload images?

Answer (score 1):

using react-native-image-crop-picker github link is https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker to pick the image

```js
_handlePhotoPress = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      cropping: true,
      mediaType: 'photo'
    })
      .then(image => {
        this.setState({ pic: image.sourceURL, file: image })
        console.log(image)
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file', image)
        formData.append('upload_preset', 'XXXX')
        return axios({
              method: 'post',
              url: 'yourUrl',
              data: formData,
              headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                  //handle success
                  console.log(response);
              })
              .catch(function (response) {
                  //handle error
                  console.log(response);
              });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
     })
  }
```

https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker to pick the image

Comment: I want to show photos in my application not opening user gallery.

Answer (score 0):

In debugger react-native, you need to remove the debugger global configuration to make FormData works.

For example:

```
GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest
```

Reference issues:
https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/38

Comment: Where are should put them?

Comment: remove any global settings inside your project, you can go to the reference link for more details

Comment: Where I should find global settings?